English translation of Delone-Ryshkov (1967)
I was looking for an english translation of this article in Russian A contribution to the theory of the extrema of a multidimensional $\zeta-$function, does there exist one?

I would look in the 1967 volume of Soviet Mathematics. Doklady, which many university libraries will have. It might be among these volumes of this translation journal at the Internet Archive.
